# Is it possible that a Logitech wireless mouse connected over bluetooth to a linux machine consumes more power, than when connected to other OS?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, power-management, battery

I have got a Logitech M590 connected over Bluetooth to my Ubuntu 19.10 (up-to-date), and it turns out that the battery of the mouse runs out after about two months while Logitech advertises two years of battery.

My question is whether it is possible that a device connected to a linux machine needs more power to run than when it is connected to a Windows / MacOS.

I have checked `upower --dump` but the mouse's power level is not available there... (It tells percentage 100%, state unknown, battery-missing-symbolic).

Thanks in advance !

--

**Important edit:** I placed a post-it inside my battery compartment with the date I placed a brand new Duracell AA battery, and the battery stopped working after 56 weeks, so just after a year. **I have thus no reason any more to believe that battery life is significantly reduced in Ubuntu (using the unifying connector).**
But the low-battery notifications in Ubuntu started after only two months, although the battery was far from empty...

I thus plan to change my battery every two months, and then use the old yet still almost full battery for other purposes because it drove me mad to get so many notifications (I pushed the experience only to see how long the battery would last).

Comment: I had one at work (Microsoft's Windows XP: it was a while ago). I got fed up changing he battery every month or so. They could probably to 2 years if you don't use them.

Comment: Hi I have a MX510 which last around 1 1/2 year with it's battery on Fedora rolling release.

Comment: Working with other wireless devices, I would speculate that it would use more battery if it was struggling to connect, frequently disconnecting, etc. This *could be* the operating system, or a particular driver, the operating environment, or code on either end. Or you could just have a crummy battery - did you check it's expire date? Was it installed fresh? Has this happened repeatedly for many cycles? Do you have a collection of other batteries and wireless mice that you are using as a control group (likely, hah! ) ? I would not jump to any conclusion based on a single incident.

Comment: I have the same question! I havw purchased an MX Ergo M575 and after two months the battery level is at 15% which is less than ideal!

Comment: @FarhoodET you may consider configuring the unifying connector using `solaar`.

Comment: @JohannesLemonde I'm using Solaar.:(